# How to Turn On/OFF Monitor Raspberry using IR transmitter?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, infrared

I installed a Infrared receiver/transmitter on my Raspberry PI.
It's possible to turn on/off TV using command line?

Comment: Show us what you tried... You did search before asking, did you ?

Comment: Well, if you have an IR RX/TX, what is the barrier?. I am pretty sure the serial codes are around there...